# How do I preg_match a word inside of a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to pregmatch the name of a file for ".msi" and ".php", but even though the file has that type of file type, it won't detect it.

Here is my code:

```
$uploaded_type = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    if (preg_match('#\b(msi|php)\b#', $uploaded_type,)) { 
    echo $uploaded_type; }
```

It keeps on passing through and never detects it.
the file that I am testing with is named "install.msi"
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the content of `$uploaded_type`?

Comment: The trailing comma would be a syntax error prior php 7.3

Comment: That regex is would allow `test_msi.exe`... or should. What does `var_dump($uploaded_type)` give? Also strange that you'd want an `image` with a `php` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code has a typo with extra `,` if you use it prior to php **7.3** version. [SEE HERE](https://3v4l.org/bKA7l)

```
<?php
$uploaded_type = 'install.msi';
if (preg_match('#\b(msi|php)\b#', $uploaded_type,)) { 
    echo $uploaded_type; 
}
?>
```

Output for **7.3.0 - 7.3.3**

```
install.msi
```

Output for **7.1.25 - 7.2.16**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in on line 3
>       Process exited with code 255.

So when I remove the trailing comma `,` then it works perfectly. [SEE](https://3v4l.org/Qgc5v)

```
<?php
$uploaded_type = 'install.msi';
if (preg_match('#\b(msi|php)\b#', $uploaded_type)) { 
    echo $uploaded_type; 
}
?>
```

But I would prefer a **non-regex** way with `pathinfo()` and `in_array()` that will work for most of the php version. Let's do it like-

```
<?php
$uploaded_type = 'install.msi';
$info = pathinfo($uploaded_type);
$valid_file_extensions =  ['msi','php','jpg'] ;;
if (in_array($info["extension"],$valid_file_extensions)) {
  echo $uploaded_type;   
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/QGrRr